# Xamarin Forms Maps Pin showed on android emulator but not showed on android device

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.maps

I have developed an application in `xamarin` for android with `xamarin.forms.maps`. In the android emulator when debugging works correctly. Debugging on an android device still shows the map but neither centers the map on the past coordinates nor draws the pin.

```
public void LoadMapa(){
            var mainViewModel = MainViewModel.GetInstance();
            var lat = Convert.ToDouble(mainViewModel.Vehiculo.Vehiculo.Lat);
            var lon = Convert.ToDouble(mainViewModel.Vehiculo.Vehiculo.Lon);
            var pin = new MapaPin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(lat, lon),
                Label = "Xamarin San Francisco Office",
                Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA",
                Id = "Xamarin",
                Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
            };
            customMap.MapaPins = new List<MapaPin> { pin };
            customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
            customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new 
            Position(lat, lon), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, if solved problem, remember to share your answer or mark the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough code to see where you get the `Vehiculo.Lat` and `Vehiculo.Lon` from.

Is it perhaps a problem with your device culture settings and consequently the `Convert.ToDouble(...)` fails? I had such problems with decimal comma / decimal point.

Comment: Solved, the problem was in the conversion. I tried with the Lat and Lon values ​​literally (40.1235, -3.810202) and it worked on the android device. I have modified it so that the parameters are double instead of string to eliminate the conversion and it already works. Thank you.